# Migrate from GCM 2.0 to GCM 3.0 InstanceID API

Tags: android, google-cloud-messaging

Currently I have released my application on play store and in that project i am using

```
compile 'com.google.android.gms:play-services:7.0.0'
```

Google play services Library Version `7.0` to implement Push notification using Google cloud messaging in my project.

Google play services library version `7.0` uses old registration procedure using `register()` method

```
GoogleCloudMessaging.register(SENDER_ID);
```

But Googel documentation says.

> GCM register() is deprecated starting May 28, 2015. New app
>   development should use the Instance ID API to handle the creation,
>   rotation, and updating of registration tokens

`InstanceID API` includes in Google play services version `7.5` so i have to migrate from `7.0` to `7.5` or more. But application is already on play store which is using `GCM register()` method.

I have refer this [link](https://developers.google.com/cloud-messaging/android/client) which explains how to use `InstanceID` but i can not find any migration guide to migrate from `GCM register()` to `InstanceID`

so how can i migrate from `GCM register()` method to `InstanceID API` ?

any help will be appreciated.

Comment: 50 points bounty for finding you a link?

Comment: you can give link and proper explanation in answer

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You just have to implement the `InstanceId-API`, reregister the devices and store the new IDs on your server.

That´s how they explain migration for apps upgrading from C2DM to GCM [here](https://developers.google.com/cloud-messaging/c2dm#migrating) which where completly different services so this will work for upgrading to the latest `GCM-API` and `InstanceId-API` as well.

You should try if it is possible to mix `InstanceIDs` and old `RegIds` when sending notifications (I could not find any hint about that). If not you´ll have to save a boolean or whatever together with each ID stored on your server in order to be able to distinguish which method you should use to send a notification to a particular device.

Comment: Yes but what about Registration id stored in Preferences and my app's flow is like that when user logged in then it is registered to GCM server then user can use app without login so when if release update with new Instance id API then already logged in user are not able to register to GCM server.

Comment: second problem is that when i started using GCM 3.0 google automaticaly generates new API key but i have already old API key which is configured for Registred user. Backend pushnotification script is made in C so how can use different API key for GCM 2.0(already registred user) and GCM 3.0(new user)?

Comment: Well, an idea for a workaround would be to add another preference 'hasUpdatedToInstanceId' which defaults to false. On App-startup you could then check this value and force the device to re-register via InstanceId. Afterwards set this preference to true and your workflow would continue as usual.

Comment: I am not familiar with C so I am afraid I cannot provide you a code example but my idea would be to store wether a received Id is an InstanceId or an old RegId (pass it from your client as additional param to your backend) like I already mentioned in my answer. Depending on that additional information you could just split your notification into two requests, one for old ids with old API key in its header and one for instance ids with the new API key in its header.

Answer (score 1):

You should add GCM dependency in build.gradle of app.

```
compile 'com.google.android.gms:play-services-gcm:10.0.1'
```

Then in your activity you should add the piece of code inside **Async Task** or **Thread**,

```
String authorizedEntity = PROJECT_ID; // Project id from Google Developer Console
String scope = "GCM";
String token = InstanceID.getInstance(context).getToken(authorizedEntity,scope);
```

**LoginActivity.Java:**

```
public class LoginActivity extends AppCompatActivity{

private String deviceToken;

@Override protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstance) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstance);
    setContentView(R.layout.activity_login_new);
    ButterKnife.bind(this);

      if (!NetworkHelper.checkActiveInternet(this)) {
        Methodutils.messageWithTitle(LoginActivity.this, "No Internet Connection",
            "Please check your internet connection.", v -> finish());
      } else {
        new RegisterDevice(false).execute();
      }
    }
  }

private class RegisterDevice extends AsyncTask<String, String, String> {
    private ProgressDialog dialog;

    @Override protected void onPreExecute() {
      super.onPreExecute();

      dialog = new ProgressDialog(LoginActivity.this);
      dialog.setMessage("loading...");
      dialog.setCancelable(false);
      dialog.show();
    }

    @Override protected String doInBackground(String... params) {
      try {

        String authorizedEntity = AppConstants.APP_ID;
        String scope = "GCM";

        deviceToken = InstanceID.getInstance(LoginActivity.this).getToken(authorizedEntity, scope);

        Log.e("New Device Token - ", deviceToken != null ? deviceToken : "NA");
        if (deviceToken != null) {
          return deviceToken;
        }
      } catch (IOException e) {
        e.printStackTrace();
      } catch (Exception e) {
        e.printStackTrace();
      }
      return null;
    }

    @Override public void onPostExecute(String result) {
      super.onPostExecute(result);
      if (dialog.isShowing) {
        dialog.dismiss();
      }
      if (result == null) return;
    }
  }

}
```

Comment: Thanks for the help.